# Change SystemTray.IsVisible during runtime (code)? Windows Phone 7 Related

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Can I disable SystemTray.IsVisible during runtime so my consumers can hide the systemtray or show it when they want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it and see instead of asking? It takes longer to write the question, than to write the code for it.

But I would recommend against it. The SystemTray automatically hides itself (but keep it's allocated 12 pixels), and only show when you tap at the top.

Changing it's Opacity, and adjusting the Background to match that of your app, it's a much better idea.

Comment: Who even notices the system tray anyway? I've never seen an app where I wished I had the option to toggle on/off 12 pixels...

Comment: Me neither. And I use a transparent system tray in a bunch of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try this anywhere ... Note too that this also applies to WP8

```
PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
if (frame != null)
{
    PhoneApplicationPage page = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;

    if (page != null)
    {
        SystemTray.SetIsVisible(page, false);
    }
}
```